# Error loading AGSMap: "Webmap version is not supported"

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I'm trying to load a map in an iOS app from an on-premise instance of ArcServer.

```
func initMap() {
    self.mapView.map = AGSMap.init(url: URL(string: self.mapLayerUrl)!)

    self.mapView.map?.load(completion: { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error loading map: ", error?.localizedDescription ?? "???")
            return
        }
        //Success branch never reached
    })
}
```

This always triggers the error branch and logs the message "webmap version is not supported". [This article](https://community.esri.com/thread/199854-webmap-version-not-supported) indicated the map is out of date and needs to be saved. I navigated to the map through the ArcGIS Server site, selected "ArcGIS Online Map Viewer" and saved it. However, that did not solve the issue.

Can someone suggest another way to troubleshoot this?